# how to display message in correct row and not all rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is a function where it controls whatever happens after a file has finished uploading in its own table row. Each table row consists of a file input where the user can upload a file and then the name of the file is appended within it's own table row.

If the file was successful then it displays a successful message, if upload was not successful then it displays a message stating there is an error. But I also have another function within the function where the user can delete a file by clicking on the "Delete" button. The only problem I have is with this line of code:

```
$(".imagemsg").html(data);
```

Let's say that I have 2 table rows, and I delete a file in the first row, the message within .imagemsg should only be displayed in the first row as that was the row the deletion occured, it shouldn't display the message in the first and second row.

So my question is what do I need to add to `$(".imagemsg").html(data);` so that the message is only displayed within the row the deletion of the file occured and not in all `.imagemsg` which is in every row?

Below is full code:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

      var result = '';

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';      
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="imageemsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }


      $(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {

         var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');

        $(this).parent().remove();

    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)
      .done(function(data) {
        $(".imagemsg").html(data);
       });


    });

      return true;   
}
```

Comment: Should be tagged "Jquery" as well.

Comment: Does anyone know how to achieve Kolink's answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the relevant element to the callback function. You already have `$(this)`, so you can probably get the right row from that and put it in a variable, then access it in the callback to put the result in the right place.

Comment: I included the call back function at the bottom of the question. Are you saying to pass var image_file_name? where do I place $image_file_name in the call back function? Does it go right at the end?